# Jenkins Windows batch command cd not working

Tags: jenkins

[image]

Why not working a simple cd command?
I want to compile a simple java program, but the directory does not changed.

[image]
The `pwd` print out the workspace directory, not the expected `d`

This screenshot comes from a Udemy course: it must be work...
[image]

Comment: Try `cd d:\ && pwd` and see if that works.